# Styling orchard menu with custom css

Tags: c#, .net, css, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

Currently I am implementing an existing layout already implemented in MVC4 project.

I am struggling with how to implement a custom menu in the latest Orchard (using the source version so Orchard runs in Visual Studio).

The problem is where does the CSS get applied? The only thing I could find with google was changing the `Menu.cshtml` (one in core/shapes one in admin theme, clueless which one is the proper one). I cannot see any sign of css anywhere.

The html version of my menu has the following look:

```
<div id="cssmenu" class="fixedContentSize">
    <ul>
        <li class='active '><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Dojo</span></a>
        <ul>
                <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Test</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Test2</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Media</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Links</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets applied in the theme's CSS. Look at site.css in the theme machine theme for an example.

Comment: Hello Bertrand, where do these styles get applied to? I already have plans to implement a second menu in my application but at the moment I would be not be able to do so. In short what are the proper files to modify/look at when we are talking about menus/navigation Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. They target nav > ul > li and what's under. Open the file and check it out for yourself.

Comment: My question might have been a bit confusing. I have successfully customized my menu with a new css layout. But what if i want to place a second menu somewhere on my screen, how does that work (for example a second menu that will appear in 3 pages, but the default menu should always remain visible)? Meaning where can i really customize my menu and see "how" it is build.

Comment: You can use the class of a container to differentiate them in CSS, such as the zone or the widget. Inspect the element above your menu in your browser's dev tools.